# Facebook login immediate mode?

Tags: facebook, oauth

I'm using Facebook OAuth interface but can't get immediate mode parameter working. Do you have any idea how that works with FB or any other url to use instead?!

(I don't/can't use FB JS libraries.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have extracted following url from FB php-sdk (which Quentin reminds me):

```
https://www.facebook.com/extern/login_status.php
  ?api_key=<your app-id or api-key>
  &no_user=<callback url>
  &no_session=<callback url>
  &ok_session=<callback url>
  &session_version=3
```

When you redirects user to above url (or open it as an iframe or popup) Facebook silently/immediately redirects backs user/browser to:

- `no_user` when user has NOT signed in.
- `no_session` when user has signed in but has NOT authorized your app yet.
- `ok_session` when user has signed in and already authorized your app. Additional parameters (user identification and required token) will be appended to this url by FB which you need to validate.

For example:

```
https://www.facebook.com/extern/login_status.php
  ?api_key=123456789012345
  &no_user=http://example.com/signin/fb/no_user
  &no_session=http://example.com/signin/fb/no_session
  &ok_session=http://example.com/signin/fb/ok_session
  &session_version=3
```

Put them in one line whit no spaces and don't forget to encode urls if needed.

See OpenID Immediate mode to find out why this is useful.

Comment: I did not know about the url. Could you share how you use it ? What code do you put in your `no_user` `no_session` and `ok_session` url ?

Comment: I meant : what action are you taking on the 3 landing pages ? What java code (authenticating user, rendering login link, redirecting him to facebook, storing access token, ...)

Comment: This is used to automatically sign in user (without landing on FB sign in page) if (a) she has already signed in with FB (has a live session with FB) and (b) has previously authorized your app. On ok_session you get enough info to identify user and start a session but on no_session/user you consider user as not-signed-in-yet-visitor.

Answer (score 2):

A great way to make users login into your website with their Facebook account is to use the Facebook PHP SDK ([see on github](https://github.com/facebook/php-sdk)). So you will have something like :

```
require "facebook.php";
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
    'appId'  => YOUR_APP_ID,
    'secret' => YOUR_APP_SECRET,
));

$user = $facebook->getUser();
```

If the user is logged in, then `$user` is his Facebook ID. You then have to check if you have a valid access token by making an API call :

- If it does not raise any exception, then you have a valid access token
- If it does, then you have to re-authenticate the user.

Here you go :

```
if ($user) {
  try {
    $facebook->api('/me');
  } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
    $user = null;
  }
}
```

You need then to display the login or logout link :

```
<?php if ($user): ?>
    <a href="<?php echo $facebook->getLogoutUrl() ?>">Logout of Facebook</a>
<?php else: ?>
    <a href="<?php echo $facebook->getLoginUrl() ?>">Login with Facebook</a>
<?php endif ?>
```

When the user is logged in and you have a valid access token, you can make API calls to get data from Facebook :

```
$user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
```

You may want to check the [example page of the Facebook PHP SDK](https://github.com/facebook/php-sdk/blob/master/examples/example.php) which is well documented.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks, I'm not using php, but it helped me to find the answer.

Comment: I'm using Java. See my answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6173248/facebook-oauth-immediate-mode/6180785#6180785

Answer (score 0):

If you are developing java based application, in that case you can use SoicalAuth library.

http://code.google.com/p/socialauth/